# ActionBar , TabLayout are leaving (unnecessary ) space after become hidden , Gone

Tags: android, autolayout

am trying to hide and show tabLayout and action bar  via some different listeners:

but after hiding them there occupied space is still exists 
please see the below images for better understanding :

**i have ActionBar + TabLayout**
[image]

Tab Changed so Action is now hidden **but still the space taken by ActionBar exists**

[image]

SaerchBegins now am hiding the TabLayout but still **getting same Behaviour** (the Blank Space is still here )

[image]

this is how am hiding and them :

//TabLayout

```
 tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 tabLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

// actinBar

```
 actionBar.hide();
```

how to fix this ? anyone ? any clue ?

Comment: Use only View.GONE dont use View.INVISIBLE

Comment: okay , but problem is still here

Comment: I dont think this a good idea.

Comment: @SaeedSharman can you please elaborate ??

Comment: @remyboys hi there found any solution?

Comment: hey @MFaisalHyder it Turns out  `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` was behind all this trouble  , setting it to false did the job , till wondering why i putted this in my Xml though

Comment: and for tabLayout `View.Gone` Did the Job

Comment: @remyboys glad to hear that u solved it, will try then tell, my implementation is bit old, i am using SlidingTablayout with viewpager for recyclerview and holding fragments. will shift to Design support library if this persists :)

Comment: oh thats good @MFaisalHyder best of luck for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turns out the extra unwanted space was just because of :

`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

changing it to `false` did the job

Comment: This error is really annoying  I took me an hour to play around with it. your answer really help. Thanks